# How to stop "tel:number" links from working on desktop / tablets

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, user-agent

This must be very common.... I apologize, but can't find a working solution here...

I'm working on a site (retrofit) and it has responsive CSS such as:

```
/* Refecence from responsive.css
/* crank up to 5000px to support high res monitors and TV's */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 5000px) 
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop - BROWSER SIZE 2 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1200px) 
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet - BROWSER SIZE 3 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 991px) 
/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) - BROWSER SIZE 4 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) 
/* Landscape phones and down - BROWSER SIZE 5 */
@media (max-width: 480px) 
/* iphone portrait mode - BROWSER SIZE 6 */
@media (max-width: 320px)
```

**I'm new to this, and done quite a bit of research, but I have a couple of questions:**

I have the plan to have two blocks of HTML, one hidden, and use JS or CSS to hide the appropriate block based on user being on mobile device or not.

I wish **to avoid useragent**, as there are way too many. By default, Android no longer parses numbers as such (as per other posts) without the 'tel:'. I tested on Nexus 5. On the other hand Firefox asks for device to use on a 'tel: 'link.

1. Can I use my current @media CSS blocks? If so what about retina?
2. OR can useragent based JS be ok somehow?
3. **Other options, I mean what do most people do???**

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I settled on a Javascript library isMobile.

https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile

It seems that many use it, so I assume it would work.

My worry is that if a new device comes up, i have to continually update this library...